# multi cloned select menu to submit form using Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

im trying to make a simple form which have a select menu with clone and remove button and once any of those select menus changed it must post the form using .Ajax call .
its working but have some issues
HTML

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="LangForm" >
<div id="fileds">
<select name="lang[]" id="lang" class="lang">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="arabic">Arabic</option>
<option value="english">english</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
<button class="clone">Clone</button> 
<button class="remove">Remove</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
     var counter = 1;
    $(".clone").click(function(){
        $('#lang').clone().appendTo('#fileds');
        counter++ ;
    });
    $(".remove").click(function(){
        if (counter > 1) {
        $('#lang:last').remove();
        counter-- ;
        }       
    });
    $('.lang').change(function(){ 
    $.ajax({type:'POST', 
        url: 'action.php', 
        data:$('#LangForm').serialize(), 
        success: function(response) {
        $('#content').html(response);
    }
    });
    });
});
```

it have 2 issues
first one when i click the remove button it remove the original select menu first then the cloned one and keep the last cloned one what i need is to remove the cloned menus first and keep the original one

second issue its submit form only when original menu changed what i need is to submit form whenever any menu changed original or cloned.
below is the PHP code from the action PHP page its something simple just to show result
PHP

```
<?php
print_r ($_POST['lang']);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: if you have two separate issues, you should make two separate questions

Comment: @tereško i thought it would be spam :( since they are related to each other

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="LangForm" >
<div id="fileds">
    <select name="lang[]" class="lang">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="arabic">Arabic</option>
        <option value="english">english</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
<button class="clone">Clone</button> 
<button class="remove">Remove</button>
<div id="content"></div>​
```

Note: Id of the field has been removed.

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $(".clone").click(function(){
        // clone(true) will clone the element with event handlers intact. 
        $('.lang').last().clone(true).appendTo('#fileds');
    });

    $(".remove").click(function(){
        var selects = $('.lang');
        if (selects.length > 1) {
            selects.last().remove()
        }
    });
    $('.lang').change(function(e){
        // console.log(e)
        $.ajax({type:'POST', 
                url: 'action.php', 
                data:$('#LangForm').serialize(), 
                success: function(response) {
                $('#content').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/kFB5j/1/